# Find elements of a matrix from another

Tags: matlab, matrix

I am work from a skeleton of an image. Wanting to fill some incomplete branches, I extracted the end points of the skeleton and implemented Dijkstra's algorithm to find the minimal paths that can be between the points (I get a matrix FR 500x500).

I applied a constraint of cost and orientation to limit the undesirable connections. My problem is that I still have unwanted links because some starting point belong to several paths with different costs. Then I extracted these starting points to keep only those whose cost is the lowest (matrix P 75x3 with column 1 and 2 which are the coordinates X and Y of the starting points and column 3 the cost).

I now try to code that I want to take all possible paths those who have a starting point and a cost corresponding to the matrix FP but I do not see how to do.

I would like to indicate in this code that each starting point has the "right" to take only the least expensive path

```
NumberPath = 0;
S=size(EP); %EP = matrix 90x2 coordinates x and y of skeleton's end points 
NumP=S(1);

for i=1:NumP-1
    for j=i+1:NumP
        FP = ED(i,:);
        LP = ED(j,:);
        [cost,path] = dijkstra(PC,Weight); % PC = matrix of all possible paths
        dimPath = size(path);

        dx=LP(1)-FP(1);
        dy=LP(2)-FP(2);

        if dx>0 && dx/dy>0 % Constraints of orientation

           NumberPath = NumberPath+1;

    if (cost<55) % Constraints of Cost
    for p=1:dimPath(2)
        FR(PC(path(1,p),2),PC(path(1,p),1))=NumberPath; 
   % FR=Matrix 500x500 with all paths according to conditions 

        Cost(i,j)=cost;            % Matrix of all cost < 55

         P(NumberPath,:)=FP;      % Starting Point of each path
         L(NumberPath,:)=LP;      % End Point of each path

   end
        end
   end
end
```

Comment: I don't understand the goal of your matrix FP, ok cool, you find the minimal cost corresponding to each starting point but you lose all the informations concerning the path, so for me this matrix is useless. You should keep a square matrix. BTW how do you determine which node is connected to another node (in order to create your graph) ?

Comment: I choose to create the matrix FP because I don't know how to select the minimal cost correponding to each starting point with a square matrix... And to determine which node is connected to another node I thought to do as for the starting points but for the end points (in a matrix LP for example) and to code to take the path that goes from the starting point 1 to the end point 1 and with the cost 'c'. But I realize that this is not really a good idea..

Comment: @obchardon What I would like to do is to say after the constraint of cost and orientation that I wish to keep only one path per starting point and this path being the one with the lowest cost

Comment: Ok, so when you say "Constraint of cost and orientation" I suppose that you're talking about a "directed adjacency matrix"? But if you want to calculate a cost you need a starting point and an end point. How can you calculate the lowest cost based on only one node ?

Comment: Yes I think we can use the term adjacency matrix. I will try to reformulate the problem.
In fact my costs are already calculated thanks to the function Dijkstra: each path has its cost. When I look at the matrix I notice that some paths have the same point of departure and I want to indicate that each starting point has the "right" to take only the least expensive path. I do not know if I'm lighter :-/

Comment: @obchardon I edit my question with a piece  of code

Comment: @obchardon It's ok I found an alternative. Thanks to you for help :-D